# If user makes no selection from <select>, assign a value of "Blank" with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, html-select

I would like the page to post a value I set ("BLANK") whenever there is no selection made in  dropdown. However, I wish to have the first option selected and disabled. Is there a way to work around the "null" value when disabled is present?

```
<form onsubmit="check()">
  <select id="test0">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
  </select>
  <select id="test1">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
  </select>
  <select id="test2">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option value="Alice">Alice</option>
  </select>
  <select id="test3">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option value="Ken">Ken</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```
function check() {
  let a = '#test';
  var isEmpty = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    var p = $(a + i).val();

    if (p != '') {
      isEmpty = false;
    }
  }
  if (isEmpty) {
    $('#test0').val('BLANK');
  }
};
```

If setting a new value of existing select is impossible, then I would add a hidden input #test3

Comment: I might use hidden inputs and sync their values to the corresponding select menus on change. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b036fje7/

Comment: Did you try `<option value=""` -> `<option value="BLANK"` (might not work as `disabled='disabled'`